# Volume Permissions lost

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

Ok here is my problem:

After i restarted my Server (Windows 2008 32 Bit) the Permissions of owner creator and Everyone are gone!

I am logged in as the Local Administrator (no AD present) so I tried to reset the owner using the GUI advanced--> owner--> edit. But here i see that Administrator & Administrators are already owners.

So I try to give the CREATOR OWNER back the permissions using the "Edit" button, but I get following Error Message:

```
An Error occurred while applying security information to: D:\xxxxxx\xxxxx
The media is write protected.
```

So now after searching the internet I found out, that i do not even have permissions on the Drive itself.. so i tried to assign these using the cmd as an Administrator:

```
takeown /F D:\ /r /d y
```

but all it tells me, is that the drive is Write protected:

So I'm totaly lost and don't know how to go on from this point.

Please can anyone help me to solve this problem & to make sure it doesn't happen after every restart?

Comment: I would of put some pictures in the post, but was not allowed because of my new account.. So if you need any more specific details just ask me here or i can put up possible screen shots on my website..

Comment: Is it that I'm not specific enough or am i missing important information? If so I will try to provide it.. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to have something to do with my Adaptec RAID card. I made one Volume out of the two disks i had.

```
1. Run cmd as Administrator

2. diskpart

3. list disk

4. sel disk X

5. ATTRIBUTE disk CLEAR READONLY 

6. detail disk 

7. sel Volume X

8. ATTRIBUTE Volume CLEAR READONLY
```

Now you can reset the the ownership of the Volume using the normal security settings.

See [Microsofts Answer to this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971436) or at least the one that helped me.

Comment: I about had heart failure when I lost write access to the primary network file server. This article hit the nail on the head. Thanks.